# Install spinning up from OpenAI on macOS goes wrong

Tags: python, installation, openai-gym

I'm installing spinning up in macOS and follow the steps.
but when check my install:

```
python -m spinup.run ppo --hid [32,32] --env Walker2d-v2 --exp_name installtest
```

something goes wrong:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/Users/Leon/spinningup/spinup/utils/run_entrypoint.py", line 10, in
>   
>        thunk = pickle.loads(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(args.encoded_thunk)))
>
> File
>   "/Users/Leon/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py",
>   line 800, in _make_skel_func
>       closure = _reconstruct_closure(closures) if closures else None
>
> File
>   "/Users/Leon/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py",
>   line 792, in _reconstruct_closure
>       return tuple([_make_cell(v) for v in values])
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Your script ran fine from my command line, which means its a problem with how you installed the Gym packages.

Try this:

```
#Create virtual enviornment

conda create -n spinningup python=3.6

#Enter virtual environment

source activate spinningup

brew install openmpi

#Install spinning up

git clone https://github.com/openai/spinningup.git
cd spinningup
pip install -e .

#Check install

python -m spinup.run ppo --hid "[32,32]" --env LunarLander-v2 --exp_name installtest --gamma 0.999
```

You can run everything from the command line. That should allow you to run the LunarLander Environment. Alternatively, your script should work as well.